# Move node_modules for other computer without network access

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, firewall, node-modules

In this case, 
I have one Project with some Packages and Dependencies (Nodejs). I use NPM for manager.

My client created one Web Server VM for me, **without network access**, just one Rule on the firewall to I can call my API.

I need some way to my project works perfectly inside my client, but my VM inside my client *don't have network access*.

I searched about this on Google, but every solve results have to install other dependencies, and I need something like *copy* and *paste* for my application will execute perfectly.

I saw this dependencies, but, I'm not sure if I need to install the dependencies inside my client for get my Packages from node_modules for my application to work well.

I saw: [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox), [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/pt-BR/docs/), [npm-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-offline).

If someone use and know how to do that, please help me.
If have another way to do solved, I would like to hear.

Comment: So how _do_ you access the VM? Via ssh? In this case, you could `npm install <git remote url>` stating the `git+ssh` protocol.

Comment: In this case, I'll access the VM inside the customer network (without internet access)

Comment: well...then you would have to setup a git server with your needed modules inside the customer network...sounds not really realistic...